# Unity Vuforia Google VR - Can't make onPointerEnter to GameObject change material for itself

Tags: vuforia, pointer-events

I have two 3d buttons in my scene and when I gaze into any of the buttons it will invoke OnPointerEnter callback and saving the object the pointer gazed to.

Upon pressing Fire1 on the Gamepad I apply materials taken from Resources folder.
My problem started when I gazed into the second button, and pressing Fire1 button will awkwardly changed both buttons at the same time.

This is the script I attached to both of the buttons

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using Vuforia;
using System.Collections;

public class TriggerMethods : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
Material _mat;
GameObject targetObject;
Renderer rend;   
int i = 0;  

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        TukarMat();
}

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{        
    targetObject = ExecuteEvents.GetEventHandler<IPointerEnterHandler>(eventData.pointerEnter);       
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    targetObject = null;
}    

public void TukarMat()
{

    Debug.Log("Value i = " + i);

    if (i == 0)
    {
        ApplyTexture(i);
        i++;
    }
    else if (i == 1)
    {
        ApplyTexture(i);
        i++;
    }
    else if (i == 2)
    {
        ApplyTexture(i);
        i = 0;
    }
}

void ApplyTexture(int i)
{
    rend = targetObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rend.enabled = true;
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:                
            _mat = Resources.Load("Balut", typeof(Material)) as Material;
            rend.sharedMaterial = _mat;
            break;
        case 1:
            _mat = Resources.Load("Khasiat", typeof(Material)) as Material;
            rend.sharedMaterial = _mat;
            break;
        case 2:
            _mat = Resources.Load("Alma", typeof(Material)) as Material;
            rend.sharedMaterial = _mat;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I sensed some logic error and tried making another class to only manage object the pointer gazed to but I was getting more confused.

Hope getting some helps

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

TukarMat() is beeing called on both buttons when you press Fire1. If targetObject is really becoming null this should give an error on first button since it's trying to get component from a null object. Else, it'll change both as you said. Make sure OnPointerExit is beeing called.

Also, it seems you are changing the shared material.
The documentation suggests:

> Modifying sharedMaterial will change the appearance of all objects using this material, and change material settings that are stored in the project too.
>
> It is not recommended to modify materials returned by sharedMaterial. If you want to modify the material of a renderer use material instead.

So, try changing the material property instead of sharedMaterial since it'll change the material for that object only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've done tests on both OnPointerEnter and OnPointerExit callbacks, both worked.

Comment: @MuadzirAziz and targetObject.GetComponent<Renderer>(); is not returning null after OnPointerExit?